# Is this the correct directed graph for this relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, relations

[image: Digraph of a R]

The relations is defined by the set of ordered pairs $$R = \{(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,4),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}.$$
Please excuse my drawing, I'm very sorry for it, I hope it's understandable though.

Comment: It's correct. You may want to use [some software](http://www.graphtheorysoftware.com/) for drawing nicer graphs :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply I really appreciate it. Hahaha i know I'll surely use it next time :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

community wiki answer so that this post can be closed

As M. Vinay indicated in the comments, your answer is correct.